# Python Detect if one-to-one onto mapping exists

Tags: python, set, one-to-one, relation

Given a collection and a set of relations between them, I'd like to check if there exists a one-to-one & onto subset in the relations. (Ideally I'd also like to GET those subsets)

For example:

```
Collection: [a, b, c]
Relations: (a, b), (a, c), (b, c), (b, a)
a - b, c
b - c, a
c - ?
NONE

Collection: [a, b, c]
Relations: (a, b), (b, c), (c, a), (c, b)
a - b
b - c
c - a, b
(a, b), (b, c), (c, a)
```

I'd like to know if there's a nice, pythonic way to accomplish this.

Comment: Can we see what you have tried?

Comment: Hello thatbrod!  People will be much more inclined to help you if you show the code that you have right now.  Plus you'll get a more meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
relations = [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'a'), ('c', 'b')]
collection = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then do this:

```
mapping = collections.defaultdict(list)
for key, value in relations:
    mapping[key].append(value)
```

Finally, check these conditions:

```
if (len(mapping) == len(collection) and
    len(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mapping.values()))) == len(collection)):
    print('A bijection exists')
```

Finding the bijection is left as an exercise for the reader.